# hibernate update when @JoinTable null auto delete join table

Tags: hibernate, null, join

For clarity, I have put key code block only.

---

### 3 tables: role, action, role_action.

role_action is intermediate table and has 2 foreign keys: roleid, actionid.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "role", schema = "test")
public class Role implements Serializable  {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...
    private List<Action> action;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_action", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actionid"))
    public List<Action> getAction() {
        return action;
    }
}
```

When I modify role in web page and submit on update data, my action calls the hibernate update.

Since I only update name of role, so action field is null, and I got The log like this:

```
2016-01-06 13:44:05,011 {Slf4jLogger.java:16} - createCompositeTransaction ( 300000 ): created new ROOT transaction with id 172.16.20.151.tm0002700023
Hibernate: update test.ROLE set name=? where ID=?
Hibernate: delete from ROLE_ACTION where ROLEID=?
```

Yes, role_action got deleted.

I searched google with 'hibernate update ignore null', and added `@DynamicUpdate`, But still it is not working.

I know I can get role entity by id and then merge with update entity(from web submit), to make action not null.

But is there any way like `@DynamicUpdate`, so that I can ignore this JoinTable null association. To just update role, not delete role_action.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add this to your join column:

```
@JoinTable(name = "role_action", updatable = false, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "actionid"))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. `updatable`  seem to be old. I use hibernate-4.3.6, hibernate-jpa-2.1.  JoinTable has not `updatable ` field.